# change download folder based on website from which I download

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, data-transfer, chrome-extensions

Is it possible to change Downloads folder in Google Chrome (or any other browser) on the fly, based on the website from which I download?

Example: I start downloading on `facebook.com` and it downloads the file in `~/Downloads/Facebook`. If I start the download from `stackoverflow.com` than the file is downloaded into `~/Downloads/Stackoverflow`.

How can I achieve this? I imagine it would be possible to write a Stay Open AppleScript application that starts at computer startup and than continuously check domain name of my current tab. Not sure how I would change downloads folder on the fly though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a [folder action](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167157/software-utilities/automate-tasks-with-folder-actions.html) script which would parse your downloaded files metadata and move them into folders based on `kMDItemWhereFroms` [metadata attribute](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mdls/) value.

Or just use [Downloads Router](https://bitbucket.org/lfk/downloads-router-chrome-extension) Chrome Extension with predefined location rules.

Answer (score 2):

I know two products that do near the same thing as you want:

1. [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) (14-Day Trial): You can write rules to do actions when events are occurred.
2. [SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safaristand/) (Open Source): If you use OS X older that 10.11 it can be used. Although you can install `SafariStand` only on `Safari` and it organized downloaded files according to the date of download. You can use the [source](https://github.com/hetima/SafariStand) and find out how to customize and rebuild it.